# How to implement the adding of new users in an app using facebook´s list of friends?

Tags: facebook

I am looking for the documentation of the feature you can see in apps like Instagram or Duolingo, where you link your facebook account and allows you to add new friends based on the friends you have in your facebook account.I have been searching for the documentation or the name of this tool or implementation but so far nothing. Any ideas about this or where can I find more info?

Comment: You can ask Facebook to get a list of Facebook friends that the user have that are also using the app.

Comment: How? What is the name of the feature do you know it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

Comment: Thanks a lot WizKid